# Adjustment of the button appears after the waiting counter

Tags: javascript, html, css

The button appears after the wait counter that appears automatically when the page is loaded

I want the counter to appear only after pressing the button and the seconds counter appear and then the button to be converted to appears inside the <a tag

```js
var downloadButton = document.getElementById("download");
var counter = 10;
var newElement = document.createElement("p");
newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in 10 seconds.";
var id;
downloadButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, downloadButton);
id = setInterval(function() {
counter--;
if(counter < 0) {
newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton, newElement);
clearInterval(id);
} else {
newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in " + counter.toString() + " seconds.";
}}, 1000);
```

```html
<button id="download"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/">Watch</a></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that handles the action. Then pass it to an EventListener triggered on button click.
*The function will run after you click the button*

```js
var downloadButton = document.getElementById("download");
var counter = 10;
var newElement = document.createElement("p");

downloadButton.addEventListener('click', () => countDown())

const countDown = () => {
  newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in 10 seconds.";
  var id;
  // Reset the counter
  counter = 10
  downloadButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, downloadButton);
  id = setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if (counter < 0) {
      newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton, newElement);
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in " + counter.toString() + " seconds.";
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<button id="download"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/">Watch</a></button>
```

Comment: Goes to the link without waiting for the seconds counter

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: When you click on the button, the seconds counter appears, and after the countdown is completed, the link button appears, and when you click on it, it moves to the link

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="download" onclick="count()"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/">Watch</a></button>

<script>
function count() {
    var downloadButton = document.getElementById("download");
    var counter = 10;
    var newElement = document.createElement("p");
    newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in 10 seconds.";
    var id;
    downloadButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, downloadButton);
    id = setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if(counter < 0) {
    newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton, newElement);
    clearInterval(id);
    } else {
    newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in " + counter.toString() + " seconds.";
    }}, 1000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Goes to the link without waiting for the seconds counter

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

So to my understanding, the flow you want is the following:

1. Click button
2. Countdown starts (replacing the button)
3. Link appears (replacing the countdown text)

First off, don't use `<a>` inside `<button>`, it really doesn't make sense to have a clickable element inside a clickable element:

Reference on MDN: [The Button element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button):

> Permitted content: Phrasing content but there must be no Interactive content

If you need the link to look like a button, use css to style it as such.

With that out of the way, start with a button element in the markup, and attach an eventListener to it that when clicked starts a countdown, and as you want, displays a link at the end of the countdown:

```js
var downloadButton = document.getElementById("download");

downloadButton.addEventListener('click', countdown);

function countdown() {
  var counter = 10;
  var newElement = document.createElement("p");
  newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in 10 seconds.";
  var id;
  downloadButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, downloadButton);

  id = setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if (counter < 0) {
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = "https://www.youtube.com/";
      link.textContent = "Watch";
      newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(link, newElement);
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in " + counter.toString() + " seconds.";
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<button id="download">Watch</button>
```